# Swift extension only for Array with objective c elements its possible?

Tags: arrays, swift

Hi All I want add Array swift extension only for Array with objective c elements  its   possible?

For example :

```
extension Array where Element:ObjectiveCClass{

 func unionWithoutDuplicatesPropertiesWithArray(array:[Element] ,key:String) -> [Element]{
    var arrayA:[Element]
    var arrayB:[Element]

    if self.count > array.count {
        arrayA = self;
        arrayB = array;
    } else {
        arrayA = array;
        arrayB = self;
    }

    for object in arrayA
    {
        if object.valueForKey(key)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
    return arrayA
 }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `Element: AnyObject` meet your requirement?

Comment: I think I need protocol for conform to objective c object only, in your case its not correct declaration

Comment: @ArtemKislitsyn Are you using an older version of Swift? If this is the case, you should update to a version that supports constraining extensions to subclasses of a class. I know that Swift 4.2 does, and probably Swift 4 and Swift 3 as well.

Comment: @ArtemKislitsyn Hmm right. But `AnyObject` is ___the protocol to which all classes implicitly conform___. So that will essentially constraint your extension to class only types. But if you're interested only for the **Objective-C** classes then you need the `NSObject`.

Comment: @sweeper swift 4.2

Comment: Now all works thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NSObject`?

> The root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies, from which subclasses inherit a basic interface to the runtime system and the ability to behave as Objective-C objects.

```
extension Array where Element: NSObject{

    func unionWithoutDuplicatesPropertiesWithArray(array:[Element] ,key:String) -> [Element]{
        var arrayA:[Element]
        var arrayB:[Element]

        if self.count > array.count {
            arrayA = self;
            arrayB = array;
        } else {
            arrayA = array;
            arrayB = self;
        }

        for object in arrayA
        {
            if object.value(forKey: key) != nil
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
        return arrayA
    }
}
```

Note that you didn't use `arrayB`'s value.

Comment: Hmm so simple :)